# how to delete folder and its sub folders using PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to delete the folder and its sub-folder. But my code didn't work it only delete's the sub-folder inside the parent folder. and the folder inside the sub-folder also didn't delete.

Here is my code

```
if(isset($_GET['delete'])&& isset($_GET['parent'])){
      $id = $_GET['delete'];
      $parent = $_GET['parent'];
      try{
        $selected = "SELECT * FROM tbl_menu WHERE parent=$id";
        $recursive = $db->prepare($selected);
        $recursive->execute();
        $result = $recursive->rowCount();
        // $countRows =$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          if($result == 0){
            $sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_menu WHERE id=$id ";
            $_SESSION['message'] = ( $db->exec($sql) ) ? 'Member deleted successfully' : 'Something went wrong. Cannot delete member';
          }else{
            $sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_menu WHERE parent=$id ";
            $_SESSION['message'] = ( $db->exec($sql) ) ? 'Member deleted successfully' : 'Something went wrong. Cannot delete member';
          }
      }
      catch(PDOException $e){
        $_SESSION['message'] = $e->getMessage();
      }
      header("location:index.php?folder=$parent");
  }
```

Here's my data

[image: my data]

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(isset($_GET['delete'])&& isset($_GET['parent'])){
          $id = $_GET['delete'];
          $parent = $_GET['parent'];
          try{
            $selected = "SELECT * FROM tbl_menu WHERE parent=$id";
            $recursive = $db->prepare($selected);
            $recursive->execute();
            $result = $recursive->rowCount();
            // $countRows =$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
              if($result == 0){
                $sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_menu WHERE id=$id ";
                $_SESSION['message'] = ( $db->exec($sql) ) ? 'Member deleted successfully' : 'Something went wrong. Cannot delete member';
              }else{
                $sub_sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_menu WHERE parent=$id ";
                $db->exec($sub_sql ) 
                $main_sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_menu WHERE id=$id ";        
                $_SESSION['message'] = ( $db->exec($main_sql ) ) ? 'Member deleted successfully' : 'Something went wrong. Cannot delete member';
              }
          }
          catch(PDOException $e){
            $_SESSION['message'] = $e->getMessage();
          }
          header("location:index.php?folder=$parent");
      }
```

Comment: Its works but the data inside the sub-folder didn't delete.